# Raspberry Pi 24/7 Modbus Rtu proyect

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, modbus

the conpany i work for is making a proyect, we made Modbus RTU connection using raspberry pi 3 as a gateway, and saving the data to Mysql. this proyect have to be 24/7 and running forever, im wondering what will be the best SD? or should i use USB? or a HDD? also, about the power supply, what could be the best for this proyect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using externally powered SSD or spinning disks (depending on how much data storage is required). Have a look at external 5.25” drives in enclosures *with good reviews*. I would personally use a Synology Diskstation, which will you upload backups to a RAID1 mirror on your LAN.

You should script a full backup (with for example `rsync -au /path1/source /path2/destination`) to run daily, at 1AM, or whenever load is expected to be minimal.

If using flash memory locally on the Pi, leave 10-20% of space unallocated for TRIM. Gparted will be useful for you to do this.

Comment: thanks for replying, rigth now in this project the data has been saved in a PC SERVER, connected by LAN, so i think Synology its too much, raspberry rigth now is just for take the data from modbus RTU RS-485 but not for saving that data, my question about SSD or HDD, is beacuse the 24/7 working, not for the size of the data that im gonna save. can you explain me about the back up a little bit please.

Comment: @FreddyAlexSaavedra What type of backup? To USB? Use an rsync cronjob to copy to folders which are named after date... YYYYMMDD. Use ext4 filesystem. Just leave the thumbdrive in the Pi, replace it when it’s full.

Comment: oh, i understand now, thanks mate! but its ok, because im using only raspberry to read data, the PC SERVER is the one who save it, so the raspberry is never gonna be full. thanks so much for your help...

Comment: @FreddyAlexSaavedra How is the PC SERVER the one to save it? How is the data copied to the PC SERVER?

Comment: a mate from our porject, he made a web service, using c# , the raspberry and the PC server is in the same LAN, so its working, to see the data he made an HTML app too, so we can have like  a "monitoring"  data process.    ... basically i dont know if you're familiar with this but we are kinda making an "SCADA" monitoring system data, but not using software, using only open source.

Comment: @FreddyAlexSaavedra Please show me diagrams and whatever else you care to share about the project

Comment: industrial device gives data using Modbus RTU 485 protocol, raspberry pi and module PI HAT 485, connected, a python code to print that data from the industrial device. and thats all, the python code only "updates" the data, the "web service" is the one who take that data, and save it.

Comment: @FreddyAlexSaavedra I just have RS485 USB dongles which present a serial interface... Is there some advantage to this HAT? What’s the length and speed of your bus?

Comment: in this application we are using only "bits" alarm data - so basically its only  0-1 information, and using a simulate software call Modbus Slave, we send and recive data from raspberry, and it was like 30 data/per second in 115000 bd speed.

Comment: yeah, i would liek to make a diagram, but i have no idea how to post it here, if you wanna i can send you by email, or discord or skype idk.

Comment: So there is only one node reporting back right now? Did you use ethernet cable, or just plain old wire? I am interested because I want to avoid gotchas later. How far away is the node? What termination resistor value did you use? Is is in another building, with a ‘different’ Gnd? Excuse my curiosity, but I am just so curious:/

Comment: hahaha its okay mate, in this app yes actually we have 12 industrial devices, but the project for our client its kinda "big" so we dont "care" about how many raspberry we buy, so basically we are using 12 raspberry for 12 devices, all the 12 raspberry are connect with the normal ethernet cable. but the raspberry and the industrial devices are like in the same panel, so rigth now is one node for each raspberry for RTU-485 Modbus, and 12 Nodes  Ethernet connection for the PC-SERVER (SQL SERVER).

Comment: we are not using any resistor, and we have no problem with the "GND" we are using only Modbus Protocol 485, 2 wires  A and B , but we tried in both occation and works fine sharing GND and not sharing.